# Making items visible in dropdown button for xs screen only

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I needed 3 items to be visible only in dropdown button in xs screen only. Please see the code and help me with it. This is the link for the webpage: https://krishna2l.github.io/coursera-test/mod3_solution/

```
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
      </div>

    <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav visible-xs">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a hef="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Help</a>
     </li></ul> 
    </div></div></nav>
```

Comment: Read doc to make dropdow first  : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/
Then display utility :
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Answer (score 0):

To hide elements simply use the .d-none class or one of the .d-{sm,md,lg,xl}-none classes for any responsive screen variation.

To show an element only on a given interval of screen sizes you can combine one .d-*-none class with a .d-*-* class, for example .d-none .d-md-block .d-xl-none will hide the element for all screen sizes except on medium and large devices.

See their official docs:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/